# Laravel : Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages

Tags: php, laravel-4

I am trying to install Laravel in local system and i am getting error.

OS : ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Webserver : Nginx

PHP : PHP 5.3.10

step 1 :

```
$ git clone https://github.com/laravel/laravel.git my_project
```

step2 :

```
my_project$ composer install
```

I am getting following error.

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - laravel/framework v4.2.1 requires php >=5.4.0 -> no matching package found.
    - laravel/framework v4.2.0 requires php >=5.4.0 -> no matching package found.
    - Installation request for laravel/framework 4.2.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v4.2.0, v4.2.1].

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion> for more details.

Read <http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.
```

Comment: What is your php version?

Comment: PHP Version 5.5.10 laravel 4.2 on maverick mac os

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Open your composer.json file and change framework version to the following:

```
"laravel/framework": "4.0.*"
```

instead of

```
"laravel/framework": "4.2.*"
```

Comment: above problem is solved but other problem is generated. Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-install-cmd event returned with an error

Comment: Error Output: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider' not found in /usr/share/nginx/www/my_projec  
  t/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php on line 123

Comment: try this "scripts": {
            "post-update-cmd": "php artisan optimize"

  
 },

Comment: or remove post-install-cmd and try

Comment: it took so many hours and so many websites to go through to get the correct solution :)

Comment: PHP Version 5.5.10 laravel 4.2 on maverick mac os does not work

Answer (score 0):

You can also solve this by upgrading your php to version 5.4.* or 5.5.* :)

Answer (score -1):

Tip for those starting out with Laravel. I solved the problem above by upgrading my PHP. Laravel requires PHP >= 5.4 http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/installation#server-requirements

Comment: This was already mentioned and, apparently, considered out of scope.